# I have a small problem in taking values from a file in c++

Tags: c++, file

I want to take the body of the map of the game the file, but I have a problem that the code is reading the file content as:

22233

31110

00000

00000

00000

and the file content is:

22222

33333

11110

00000

00000

the code is here:

```
void Map::loadMap(std::string path, int sizeX, int sizeY) {
    char tile;
    std::fstream mapFile;
    mapFile.open(path);

    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++) {
            mapFile.get(tile);
            Game::addTile(atoi(&tile),32 * x, 32 * y);
            mapFile.ignore();
            std::cout << tile;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    mapFile.close();
}
```

can you tell me where is the problem

Comment: `atoi(&tile)` is a bug. &title is not a null terminated c-string. Instead its a pointer to a single character.

Comment: `atoi` takes a "c-style" `string` with an integral value and converts it to an `int`. You are calling `atoi` with a pointer to a character. Not all pointers to characters are valid c-style strings. You can either make it a valid c-style string with a null terminator, or you can just do a little arithmetic yourself since it's only a single character. For instance, if the file contents are ASCII, then a `0` character has the ASCII value 48, so you could just convert the character to an `int` and subtract 48.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer How do you know if the file contains ASCII? What if OP is working with zOS and EBCDIC instead of ASCII? Instead of subtracting `48` you can always subtract `'0'` in C++. That will always work.

Comment: @ThomasSablik If you wrote the file, or know the person who wrote the file. Otherwise, as far as I'm aware, you can't possibly tell for certain.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer But you can always be sure that `'0' - '0' == 0`, `'1' - '0' == 1`, `'2' - '0' == 2`, ... C++ guarantees it. So don't subtract `48`. Subtract `'0'` instead.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I wasn't aware of that guarantee for every character encoding considered valid in C++. Could you link the section in the standard? I'm intrigued

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. In the C++20 draft, it's in paragraph 3 of section 5.3. Thanks; I learn something new every day. Hopefully this is helpful to the OP as well.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer AFAIK that's only true for digits since C++98.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer a side note on the version numbers in standards: They change. 5.3 could be 7.2 next week (unlikely as hell that it'll move that much, but possible) if new sections are added. Prefer to use the tags,`[lex.charset]` in this case, when referring to a section of the standard because they don't change nearly as easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the problem the commenters are mentioning (calling `atoi` on a non-null-terminated string), you're advancing the file stream by two bytes in the loop body (once in `get` and another time in `ignore`). `get` already advances the file by a byte; you don't need to do that again. In addition, you're not ignoring newlines as you should.

Other problems that aren't strictly related to the bug:

- whenever your function is called, it copies the string `path`. You should probably change the `path` argument to have the type `const std::string&` (a reference to a constant string) Better yet, pass in a `const char*`, since the `fstream` constructor and the `open` method take one anyway. (You can get this pointer from a `std::string` using the `c_str` method.)

So fixing your code would look like this:

```cpp
void Map::loadMap(const char* path, int sizeX, int sizeY) {
    char tile;
    std::fstream mapFile;
    mapFile.open(path);

    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++) {
            mapFile.get(tile);
            std::cout << tile;
            if (tile == '\n') continue;
            Game::addTile(tile - '0', 32 * x, 32 * y);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    mapFile.close();
}
```